# Symfony Private Beta Login

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm looking to setup a private beta on a symfony site I'm launching soon. I've got a list of invited people's email addresses to check against in a text file on the server, and I'd like to present people with an html form whenever they try to access the site without permission. Once a person has entered their email address, it should redirect them to the home page. The tricky part is that past that I'm using FOSUserBundle with a whole account login system already in place. How should I approach this problem? The person logging in with their email doesn't have an account yet, so I can't just add a role like INVITED_USER to their user document, so I'm thinking about trying to store their status in their session, and checking that using symfony 2.4's allow_if expression, but I get an error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidConfigurationException' with message 'Unrecognized options "allow_if" under "security.access_control.17"' in C:\wamp\www\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\ArrayNode.php on line 306

My security.yml file looks like this:

```
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email

    firewalls:
        beta:
            pattern: ^/
            anonymous: ~
            form_login:
                login_path: /beta
                check_path: /beta_invite_check
                always_use_default_target_path: true
                default_target_path: /
            logout:
                path: /logout
                target: /
        main:
            pattern:  ^/
            form_login:
                check_path: /login_check
                provider: fos_userbundle
                always_use_default_target_path: false
                default_target_path: /profile
                use_referer: true
                success_handler: security.authentication.handler

            logout:
                path:   /logout
                target: /
                invalidate_session: false
            anonymous: ~

        login:
            pattern: ^/login$
            security: false

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/beta, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/account, roles: ROLE_USER}
        - { path: /_wdt/.*, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: /_profiler/.*, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/profile, role: ROLE_USER }
        - { path: ^/submit, role: ROLE_USER }
        - { path: ^/submissions, role: ROLE_USER }
        - { path: ^/uploadCredits, role: ROLE_USER }
        - { path: ^/transactions, role: ROLE_USER }
        - { path: ^/activity, role: ROLE_USER }
        - { path: ^/browse/join, role: ROLE_USER }
        - { path: ^/browse/follow, role: ROLE_USER }
        - { path: ^/browse/unfollow, role: ROLE_USER }
        - { path: ^/player/rating, role: ROLE_USER }
        - { path: ^/, allow_if: "'BETA_ALLOWED' == request.getSession().beta" }
```

Does anyone know why this is happening? allow_if seems to be a new feature so maybe someone's bundle isn't playing nice with it? Here's my composer.json file too, just in case:

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
    },
    "require": {
        "doctrine/mongodb-odm": "1.0.*@dev",
        "doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle": "3.0.*@dev",
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.4.1",
        "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2.*",
        "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "hipaway-travel/mandrill-bundle": "dev-master",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.2.*",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.2.*",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.2.*",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.2.*",
        "jms/security-extra-bundle": "dev-master",
        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0.*@dev",
        "jms/di-extra-bundle": "dev-master",
        "sonata-project/media-bundle": "2.2.*@dev",
        "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "2.2.*@dev",
        "sonata-project/core-bundle": "2.2.*@dev",
        "sonata-project/doctrine-mongodb-admin-bundle": "2.2.*@dev",
        "avalanche123/imagine-bundle": "v2.1",
        "braintree/braintree_php" : "dev-master",
        "cometcult/braintree-bundle": "dev-master",
        "paypal/rest-api-sdk-php": "dev-master",
        "kmj/paypalbridgebundle": "dev-master",
        "hwi/oauth-bundle": "0.3.*@dev",
        "cboden/Ratchet": "0.3.0",
        "react/zmq": "0.2.*"

    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web"
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The way I've implemented this before is using an Invitation entity.

1. Generate an Invitation code and email the user with a link to the register form
2. Only accept registrations that include a valid invitation code

You'll need to [extend the registration form with the new invitation field](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_forms.md) and the [registration controller action](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_controllers.md).

Basically read this: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/adding_invitation_registration.md

:)

TLDR; Don't worry about the first login and use an invite system instead.

Comment: This is the approach that I would normally go with, however as I said in the question, I do not want to create a User when a beta code is entered; I only want to grant the client access to the site (Where they can then register if they want to). I've tried doing that using the client's session, and checking using the allow_if option, but for some reason it's throwing an error. Do you have any idea why, or a way around using allow_if that will achieve the same result?

Comment: In that case why not just use basic http auth on the server. Link to apache docs: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/auth.html